# How to check through reg expression in JavaScript if the entered digit is of either 4 or 7 digit and then accordingly execute the function hexToRGB?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to make a function which will automatically take user input and checks which format it is and based on that it executes the function defined (RGBToHex or hexToRGB). Inside myfunction through regexp. I want to check for 4 digit input and 7 digit user input, but most probably it is the incorrect way, any thoughts on that?

```
function hexToRGB(h) {
  let r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;

  // 3 digits
  if (h.length == 4) {
    r = "0x" + h[1] + h[1];
    g = "0x" + h[2] + h[2];
    b = "0x" + h[3] + h[3];

  // 6 digits
  } else if (h.length == 7) {
    r = "0x" + h[1] + h[2];
    g = "0x" + h[3] + h[4];
    b = "0x" + h[5] + h[6];
  }

  return "rgb("+ +r + "," + +g + "," + +b + ")";  //variables are prepended with + to convert string back to numbers
}
//hexToRGB('2222')
//hexToRGB('4616625')

//debugger;
function RGBToHex(r,g,b) {
    r = r.toString(16);
    g = g.toString(16);
    b = b.toString(16);

    if(r.length == 1) {
        "0" + r;
    }
    else if (g.length == 1) {
        "0" + g;
    }
    else {
        "0" + b;
    }    
    return "#" + r + g + b;
}
//RGBToHex(3, 82, 252)

function myFunction() {
    let input = prompt("Please enter the digit: ");
    var re = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{4||7}/g;
    if(re.test(input)) {
        hexToRGB(input);
    }
    else {
        RGBToHex(input);
    }
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this the answer you're looking for:

```
^([0-9a-fA-F]{4}|[0-9a-fA-F]{7})$
```

Or with DRY principle:

```js
const hex = '[0-9a-fA-F]';
const re = new RegExp(`^(${hex}{4}|${hex}{7})$`);
```

You can test it with this example:

```js
const hex = '[0-9a-fA-F]';
const limit = `^(${hex}{4}|${hex}{7})$`;
const re = new RegExp(limit);

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const input = e.target;

  if (re.test(input.value)) {
    input.style.background = 'lightgreen';
  } else {
    input.style.background = 'pink';
  }

  document.querySelector('b').innerHTML = input.value.length;
});
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
input { padding: 10px; font-size: 20px; background: pink; }
```

```html
<h4>Matches only a HEX-valid 4 or 7 characters string</h4>
<input type="text" /> Length: <b>0</b>
```

Comment: Thanks my motto is to get user input and based on that functions to act to convert RGBToHex and vice versa, as i replaced reg exp. in my function it worked fine, but when i tested that with debugger for the input (3, 82, 252) the function  RGBToHex started, but suddenly it got stopped at the line g = g.toString(16); showing Typeerror Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: `RGBToHex` accept 3 arguments, but receive only 1 - `input`. That's why it fails on second argument `g`.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wanenobapa/1/edit?js,console - you can use RegExp as well to parse only numbers and then pass it to function `RGBToHex`.

Comment: @MannawarHussain jsbin saving is broken, here is the correct code https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-wind-gk0uv